# No qualifying bean of type... Error ( Spring + JavaFX )

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have this starter application with spring and javaFX, and I can't seem to get past this issue where I'm trying to get information from my JPA repository. I get the following error:
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'server.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Here is what I tried to do:

```java
package server.controller;
//...imports
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getById(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUserById(userId));
    }
}
```

Here is the repository

```java
package server.repository;
//...imports
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findUserById(long userId);
}
```

And here is the User Service that is supposed to handle my requests

```java
package server.service;
//...imports
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository users;

    public UserService(UserRepository users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public User getUserById(long id) {
        if(id < 0 || !users.existsById(id)) {
            return null;
        }
        return users.findUserById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably something is missing in your jpa configuration. Try to add @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in your configuration class

Comment: is the package of the repository also scanned by Spring DI?